# Swift question: how can we init an non-optional variable in a if else block if it's of protocol type?

Tags: swift, variables, graphql, protocols, init

In Swift, we can init a non-optional variable not immediately but later on in a if else block, for example:

```
let result: Bool
if something {
   result = computeSomething()
} else {
   result = computeSomethingElse()
}
```

But what if my variable is of protocol type? (in my example, I'd like to do this with a GraphQLMutation which is a protocol):

```
let mutation: GraphQLMutation
if something {
   mutation = StartMutation()
} else {
   mutation = StopMutation()
}
self.graphQLDataSource.set(mutation: mutation)
```

Swift compiler error says: 
`Protocol 'GraphQLMutation' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Any idea to be able to do this and avoid code repetition?

Comment: What's the definition of `GraphQLMutation`, `StartMutation` and `StopMutation`?

Comment: You have to call `self.graphQLDataSource.set(...)` in each of the branches of the `if`, there is no other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work with protocols:

```swift
protocol Foo {}
struct A: Foo {}
class B: Foo {}

let x: Foo
if Bool.random() {
    x = A()
} else {
    x = B()
}
```

It just doesn't work with protocols that have an associated type. You can only use it in a generic function. Here's some code showcasing it:

```swift
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype T
}
struct A: Foo {
    typealias T = Int
}
class B: Foo {
    typealias T = String
}

func x<Foo>(_ test: Bool) -> Foo? {
    let x: Foo?
    if test {
        x = A() as? Foo
    } else {
        x = B() as? Foo
    }
    return x
}

let a1: A? = x(true)  // => A
let a2: A? = x(false) // => nil

let b1: B? = x(true)  // => nil
let b2: B? = x(false) // => B
```

- For `a1` we get an instance of `A` as the cast `A() as? Foo` worked because it has a type of `Foo` with an associated type `Int` required by the `let a1: A?`.
- For `a2` we get nil as the cast `B() as? Foo` fails because it cannot be cast into `Foo` with an associated type `Int` required by the `let a2: A?`.
- For `b1` we get nil as the cast `A() as? Foo` fails because it cannot be cast into `Foo` with an associated type `String` required by the `let b1: B?`.
- For `b2` we get an instance of `B` as the cast `B() as? Foo` worked because it has a type of `Foo` with an associated type `String` required by the `let b2: B?`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense :)

Comment: @MathieuVandeginste feel free to accept the answer then! :)